# How do I unit test protected properties meant to be set only by NHibernate?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nhibernate, nunit, moq

I'm using NHibernate to persist this entity:

```
public class Store
{
    public int Id { get; protected set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }
}
```

Note how the `Id` property has a protected setter. This is to prevent users from changing the `Id` while still allowing NHibernate to assign it an `Id` when it saves it to the database.

In one of my unit tests, I'm using Moq with the following code to mock out my repository:

```
var mock = new Mock<IRepository>();
mock.Setup(x => x.GetById<Store>(It.IsAny<int>()))
    .Returns(new Store { Value = "Walmart" }); // can't set the ID here

var store = Repository.GetById<Store>(5);
Assert.That(store.Id == 5);
```

When I tell Moq to return a new `Store` instance, I can't assign the ID, and the unit test fails. How do I unit test this property? I don't want to change the access level of the property because I don't want users to change it manually, and yet that's exactly what I have to do here in order to test it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're not actually testing the Store class, then mock it, and use the SetupGet method:

```
var mock = new Mock<IRepository>();
var mockStore = new Mock<Store>();
mock.Setup(x => x.GetById<Store>(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(mockStore.Object);

mockStore.SetupGet(s => s.Id).Returns(5);
mockStore.SetupGet(s => s.Value).Returns("Walmart");

var store = Repository.GetById<Store>(5);
Assert.That(store.Id == 5);
```

Comment: Thanks, I never considered mocking out the store object itself!

Comment: You're welcome.  I normally use this with interfaces, but since you already have to have everything virtual for NHibernate anyway this is a great fit.

Comment: But what about the behavior if the store object is more than just a POCO?

Answer (score 16):

Just to throw this out there as another approach, you could make the setter `protected internal`:

```
public class Store
{
    public int Id { get; protected internal set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }
}
```

and use the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("StoreUnitTests")]
```

Comment: Note that `StoreUnitTests` should be _assembly_ (not namespace or class) name.

Answer (score 9):

In the test project create a child class of `Store` that allows for customization of the protected properties.

```
class TestableStore : Store { 
  public int TestableId { 
    get { return Id; }
    set { Id = value; }
  }
}
```

Then setup your unit tests to use return this instance when you need to construct a `Store` object.

```
mock
  .Setup(x => x.GetById<Store>(It.IsAny<int>()))
  .Returns(new TestableStore { Value = "Walmart", TestableId=42 });
```

Comment: FYI, just need to add the Store class as the base class (I am not powerful enough to edit :()

Comment: Brilliant! Old post but useful!

Comment: While the accepted answers worked for the OP's specific problem, I think this is the best answer for where mocking is not an option as encapsulation is preserved in the domain.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly not the best approach, but you could also use reflection to set the property as is done in [Sharp Architecture's](https://github.com/sharparchitecture/Sharp-Architecture/blob/48fbcefdde0e9ca88ca42cbb106540954e687037/Src/SharpArch.Testing/Helpers/EntityIdSetter.cs) tests:

```
namespace SharpArch.Testing.NUnit.Helpers
{
    using System.Reflection;

    using SharpArch.Domain;
    using SharpArch.Domain.DomainModel;

    /// <summary>
    ///     For better data integrity, it is imperitive that the <see cref = "Entity.Id" />
    ///     property is read-only and set only by the ORM.  With that said, some unit tests need 
    ///     Id set to a particular value; therefore, this utility enables that ability.  This class should 
    ///     never be used outside of the testing project; instead, implement <see cref = "IHasAssignedId{IdT}" /> to 
    ///     expose a public setter.
    /// </summary>
    public static class EntityIdSetter
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///     Uses reflection to set the Id of a <see cref = "EntityWithTypedId{IdT}" />.
        /// </summary>
        public static void SetIdOf<TId>(IEntityWithTypedId<TId> entity, TId id)
        {
            // Set the data property reflectively
            var idProperty = entity.GetType().GetProperty("Id", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

            Check.Ensure(idProperty != null, "idProperty could not be found");

            idProperty.SetValue(entity, id, null);
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Uses reflection to set the Id of a <see cref = "EntityWithTypedId{IdT}" />.
        /// </summary>
        public static IEntityWithTypedId<TId> SetIdTo<TId>(this IEntityWithTypedId<TId> entity, TId id)
        {
            SetIdOf(entity, id);
            return entity;
        }
    }
}
```